# Unity camera broken and moves uncontrollably

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a camera in Unity work for first person. I have 2 objects. One is the camera. It has a Rigidbody and a collision the other is a box that stays in front of the camera. For some reason if I look in a certain direction the camera moves away. These are the scripts

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed=20;
    public float sens=360;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce( new Vector3(speed, 0, 0)-rb.velocity);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce( new Vector3(-speed, 0, 0)-rb.velocity);
        }
            if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce( new Vector3(0, 0, speed)-rb.velocity);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce( new Vector3(0, 0, -speed)-rb.velocity);
        }
         float speex = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime;
         float speey = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime;
        rb.transform.Rotate(sens*speey,sens*speex , 0);
         rb.transform.Rotate(0,0 , 0);
        rb.transform.localEulerAngles=new Vector3(rb.transform.localEulerAngles.x,rb.transform.localEulerAngles.y,0);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class blockcreate : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cam;
    public GameObject cube;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     cube.transform.position = cam.transform.forward+cam.transform.position; 
    }
}
```

I have tried messing around with the 2 codes but I have almost no ideas as the square seems to influence the camera even though there is no code for that.

Comment: Instead of moving the camera directly, try and add the camera inside your player object in the hierarchy and then move your player, and the camera will move along with the player.